# Python mock function with only specific argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-mock

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to mock a function only when a specific argument is passed. If other than the desired argument is passed, I'd like to call the original function instead.

In Python 2.7 I tried something like this:

```
from foo import config

def test_something(self):
    original_config = config # config is a Module.

    def side_effect(key):
        if key == 'expected_argument':
            return mocked_result
        else:
            return original_config.get(key)

        config.get = Mock(side_effect=side_effect)

        # actualy_test_something...
```

It won't work 'cause `original_config` is not a copy of `config`. It references the same module ending up in an infinite loop. I could try cloning the original `config` module instead but that seems to be overkill.

Is there something similar to [RSpec's mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-4/docs/method-stubs) I could use? e.g:

`obj.stub(:message).with('an_expected_argument').and_return('a_mocked_result')`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the indentation correct on `config.get = Mock...` line?

Comment: @PetrGladkikh yup it's correct.

Comment: Then I do not understand how it is executed. Both branches of `if` above it end with `return` so this line does not seem to be ever reached.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd need to store a reference to the unpatched function *first*:

```
def test_something(self):
    original_config_get = config.get

    def side_effect(key):
        if key == 'expected_argument':
            return mocked_result
        else:
            return original_config_get(key)

        config.get = Mock(side_effect=side_effect)
```

Here `original_config_get` references the original function before you replaced it with a `Mock()` object.